# Как скомпилировать .py в .exe с картинкой?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyinstaller, qrc

У меня скрипт на *PyQt5*, и в нём присутствуют картинки, 
но после компиляции **`.py`** в **`.exe`**, картинки всё так же отдельно остаются.

Как `поместить картинку в скрипт`, чтобы скрипт и фото не находились в разных местах.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Создаем файл ресурсов например  `res_1.qrc`

   ```
   <RCC>
     <qresource prefix="/">
       <file>images/head.jpg</file>
     </qresource>
   </RCC>
   ```

   Предполагаем, что картинка `head.jpg` находится в каталоге `images` (`images/head.jpg`)
2. Загрузить изображение из файла ресурсов:

   Команда преобразования    `pyrcc5 res_1.qrc -o res_1_rc.py`

   Этот способ заключается в том, чтобы преобразовать файл `res_1.qrc` в файл `res_1_rc.py` 
   Все картинка в `res_1_rc.py`
3. Пишем `main.py`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QPixmap, QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

import res_1_rc            # Здесь мы импортируем наше изображение


class ImageView(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Загрузить изображение из файла ресурсов
        # Команда преобразования    pyrcc5 res_1.qrc -o res_1_rc.py
        # Этот способ заключается в том, чтобы преобразовать файл res.qrc в файл res_1_rc.py 

        layout.addWidget(QLabel(self, pixmap=QPixmap(":/images/head.jpg")))
        # обратите внимание на формат получения картинки из res_1_rc.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ImageView()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Прячьте папку с картинкой и запускайте `python main.py`

4. `pyinstaller -c -F main.py`

   запустите `main.exe`

Comment: Не совсем понял что происходит. Мы добавили картинку  .qrc, преобразовали .qrc в .py и в файле main.py всё же используем image.jpg

Comment: вот  ссылка https://toster.ru/q/473134

Comment: @djimbosfan в файле `.qrc` мы прописали путь. Потом Загрузили  изображение из файла ресурсов `.qrc` , командой `pyrcc5 res_1.qrc -o res_1_rc.py` в файл `res_1_rc.py`. А приложении из файла `res_1_rc.py` вытягиваем картинку указав путь `":/images/head.jpg"` . Обратите внимание на двоеточие!