# После компиляции через PyInstaller приложение открывается только через консоль

Tags: python, pyqt5

Создал небольшую программу после компиляции открывается только в консоли, если использовать ключ --noconsole, то в консоли не открывается, а через двойной клик открывается через 5 минут или вообще не открывается. Windows 7 x64.
Вот код программы

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setFixedSize(1024, 768)
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle('Справочник')
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images.jpg'))

    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("border-image:url(prog.jpg);")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.page1()

    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    tools = self.menubar.addMenu('Поиск по списку')
    tools.addAction("0.Операторы Turbo Pascal", self.page1)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("1.Присваивание переменной значение выражения", self.page2)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("2.Begin___End", self.page3)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("3.Case___Of___Else___End", self.page4)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("4.For___To, Downto___Do", self.page5)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("5.Goto", self.page6)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("6.If___Then___Else", self.page7)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("7.Вызов процедуры", self.page8)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("8.Repeat___Until", self.page9)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("9.While___Do", self.page10)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("10.With___Do", self.page11)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("11.Inline", self.page12)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("12.Бинарные арифметические операторы", self.page13)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("13.Унарные арифметические операторы", self.page14)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("14.Булевы операторы", self.page15)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("15.Логические операторы", self.page16)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("16.PChar операторы", self.page17)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("17.Операторы сравнения", self.page18)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("18.Операторы множеств", self.page19)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("19.Строковые операторы", self.page20)
    tools.addSeparator()
    tools.addAction("20.Оператор '@'", self.page21)
    tools.triggered.connect(self.list.deleteLater)
    tools.triggered.connect(self.nextButton.deleteLater)
    tools.triggered.connect(self.backButton.deleteLater)

    self.menubar.setStyleSheet("""
                                  background-color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
                                  font: bold;
                                  font-family: Times New Roman;
                                  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
                                  font-size: 19px;
                                  selection-background-color: white;    
                                  """)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(0, 0, 1024, 30)

def pageparent(self):

    self.list = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(MainWindow)

    self.list.setStyleSheet("""
                                                  font: bold;
                                                  font-family: Times New Roman;
                                                  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
                                                  background: rgb(255, 215, 0);
                                                  font-size: 20px;                                                                                                                                                                     
                        """)
    self.list.setGeometry(100, 70, 850, 500)
    self.list.show()

    self.nextButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
    self.nextButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 600, 221, 61))
    self.nextButton.setObjectName("nextButton")
    self.nextButton.setText("Вперед")
    self.nextButton.setStyleSheet("""
                                              font: bold;
                                              font-family: Times New Roman;
                                              color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
                                              background: rgb(255, 215, 0);
                                              font-size: 27px;                                                                                                                                                                     
                    """)

    self.nextButton.show()

    self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
    self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 600, 221, 61))
    self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
    self.backButton.setText("Назад")
    self.backButton.setStyleSheet("""
                                                     font: bold;
                                                     font-family: Times New Roman;
                                                     color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
                                                     background: rgb(255, 215, 0);
                                                     font-size: 27px;""")
    self.backButton.show()

    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.list.deleteLater)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.nextButton.deleteLater)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.backButton.deleteLater)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.list.deleteLater)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.nextButton.deleteLater)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.backButton.deleteLater)

def page1(self):

    self.pageparent()
    text = open('1.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page2)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page21)

def page2(self):

    self.pageparent()
    text = open('2.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page3)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page1)

def page3(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('3.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page4)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page2)

def page4(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('4.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page5)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page3)

def page5(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('5.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page6)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page4)

def page6(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('6.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page7)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page5)

def page7(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('7.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page8)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page6)

def page8(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('8.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page9)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page7)

def page9(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('9.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page10)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page8)

def page10(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('10.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page11)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page9)

def page11(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('11.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page12)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page10)

def page12(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('12.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page13)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page11)

def page13(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('13.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page14)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page12)

def page14(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('14.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page15)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page13)

def page15(self):
    self.pageparent()

    text = open('15.txt').read()
    self.list.setPlainText(text)
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page16)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page14)

def page16(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('16')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page17)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page15)

def page17(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('17')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page18)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page16)

def page18(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('18')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page19)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page17)

def page19(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('19')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page20)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page18)

def page20(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('20')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page21)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page19)

def page21(self):
    self.pageparent()

    self.list.setText('21')
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(self.page1)
    self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.page20)



if __name__ == "__main__":

import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Windows')
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста вашу небольшую программу и покажите строку компиляции программы.

Comment: Опубликовал код.

Answer (score 1):

У меня никаких вопросов не возникает:

`pyinstaller -c -F questions_1017452.py`

Вот протокол. Сверте версии.

```
280 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4                                          # <<<=====
281 INFO: Python: 3.7.3                                             # <<<=====
282 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1                          # <<<=====
284 INFO: wrote D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\questions_1017452.spec
288 INFO: UPX is not available.
335 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\_Qt\\__Qt', 'D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\_pyinstaller']
335 INFO: checking Analysis
336 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
337 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
356 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
364 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
15800 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
15899 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
17110 INFO: Caching module hooks...
17138 INFO: Analyzing D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\questions_1017452.py
17444 INFO: Loading module hooks...
17445 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
17767 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
17769 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
18294 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
18295 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
18735 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
19441 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
20512 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
21801 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
21801 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
21813 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
21835 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
25386 INFO: Looking for eggs
25386 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
25390 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
25456 INFO: Warnings written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\build\questions_1017452\warn-questions_1017452.txt
25677 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\build\questions_1017452\xref-questions_1017452.html
25730 INFO: checking PYZ
25731 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
25734 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\build\questions_1017452\PYZ-00.pyz
28034 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\build\questions_1017452\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
28071 INFO: checking PKG
28072 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
28075 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
29023 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
29024 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
29027 WARNING: was placed previously at
29030 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
72109 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
72214 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-
64bit\run.exe
72215 INFO: checking EXE
72218 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
72221 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
72224 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\_Qt\__Qt\_pyinstaller\dist\questions_1017452.exe
72384 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема так и осталась, запускается только через консоль, через двойной клик по .exe не открывается.

Comment: @sergeiPython я добавил изображение, которое демонстрирует, что через двойной клик у меня также работает.

Comment: вообщем через компиляцию с консолью открывается сразу, без консоли спустя 5 минут. И нужно как то вшить картинки и текстовый файл чтобы можно было переносить одним файлом.

Comment: @sergeiPython  посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699?r=SearchResults&s=1|7.6120#998699

Comment: выдает ошибку не найден .txt , если через консоль из корня запускать тоже выдает нужно как то вышить его в .exe

Comment: @sergeiPython  Как включить текстовый файл в приложение qt? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016768/how-do-i-include-a-text-file-to-a-qt-application/21061390

Comment: А с помощью какой консольной команды Вы запускаете свой ".exe"-шник из командной строки???

Comment: @garrip91  `questions_1017452.exe`