# SVG иконка в .py файле с изменяемым цветом

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qpushbutton, qsvgwidget

Прошу показать пример с любым **`.svg`**, который будет прописан не отдельным файлом `.svg`, а в коде **main.py** с последующим применением в `setStyleSheet` `QPushButton`.

Цель - получить **один** файл **`.py`** с несколькими иконками, с возможностью задания цвета всех иконок в самой программе. (пробовал делать в *Android*, получалось...)

```
icon="""КОД SVG ФАЙЛА""" + color + """КОД SVG ФАЙЛА"""

self.NAME = QPushButton(self)
...
self.NAME.setStyleSheet(icon)
```

---

Есть такой код: (работает)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer

svg_str = """<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="35" height="35"><defs><path d="M17.5 -7.25L42.25 17.5L17.5 42.25L-7.25 17.5L17.5 -7.25Z" id="b19hNARgS3"></path></defs><g><g><g><use xlink:href="#b19hNARgS3" opacity="1" fill="#7bd0e9" fill-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>"""

svg_bytes = bytearray(svg_str, encoding='utf-8')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
svgWidget = QSvgWidget()
svgWidget.renderer().load(svg_bytes)
svgWidget.setGeometry(100,100,100,100)
svgWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

хочу получить так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 300))

        self.pb = QPushButton(self)
        self.pb.setObjectName("pb")
        self.pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 50))
        svg_str = """<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="35" height="35"><defs><path d="M17.5 -7.25L42.25 17.5L17.5 42.25L-7.25 17.5L17.5 -7.25Z" id="b19hNARgS3"></path></defs><g><g><g><use xlink:href="#b19hNARgS3" opacity="1" fill="#7bd0e9" fill-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>"""
        self.pb.setStyleSheet("#pb{;\n"
        "background-color: #000000;\n"
        "background-image: url(" + svg_str + ");\n"
        "}")

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

---

**Дополнительный вопрос:**

> А почему **%s** не работает в двух-трех местах? в кавычках?

```
self.svg_str = """
<svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 98.40 35.63 C 111.65 32.59 126.16 40.12 131.49 52.58 C 136.11 62.55 134.02 74.42 128.61 83.64 C 124.15 91.40 116.88 98.21 107.79 99.72 C 99.82 101.08 91.82 97.30 86.36 91.64 C 78.79 83.85 74.13 72.88 74.99 61.94 C 75.94 49.30 85.95 38.02 98.40 35.63 Z" />
<path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 61.84 109.81 C 74.62 106.15 87.71 102.93 101.06 102.60 C 99.42 118.09 97.06 133.51 95.27 148.98 C 95.06 150.30 95.92 151.44 96.44 152.58 C 99.06 157.18 101.67 161.78 104.39 166.32 C 107.41 161.59 110.17 156.70 112.88 151.80 C 113.76 150.47 113.66 148.84 113.47 147.33 C 111.62 132.42 109.51 117.54 107.82 102.61 C 121.22 102.92 134.33 106.17 147.15 109.84 C 151.24 111.19 155.73 112.06 159.07 114.97 C 161.95 117.47 162.87 121.37 163.27 125.01 C 165.05 141.64 166.93 158.27 168.77 174.90 C 125.92 175.12 83.07 174.96 40.22 174.98 C 41.72 159.42 43.69 143.91 45.28 128.35 C 45.85 124.11 45.87 119.31 48.91 115.95 C 52.21 112.23 57.33 111.28 61.84 109.81 Z" />
</svg>
""" % color
```

если один из цветов задать жестко, то второй работает и все нормально открывается, но если оба то ни в какую...

Забил в 1 строку:

```
<svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 98.40 35.63 C 111.65 32.59 126.16 40.12 131.49 52.58 C 136.11 62.55 134.02 74.42 128.61 83.64 C 124.15 91.40 116.88 98.21 107.79 99.72 C 99.82 101.08 91.82 97.30 86.36 91.64 C 78.79 83.85 74.13 72.88 74.99 61.94 C 75.94 49.30 85.95 38.02 98.40 35.63 Z  M 61.84 109.81 C 74.62 106.15 87.71 102.93 101.06 102.60 C 99.42 118.09 97.06 133.51 95.27 148.98 C 95.06 150.30 95.92 151.44 96.44 152.58 C 99.06 157.18 101.67 161.78 104.39 166.32 C 107.41 161.59 110.17 156.70 112.88 151.80 C 113.76 150.47 113.66 148.84 113.47 147.33 C 111.62 132.42 109.51 117.54 107.82 102.61 C 121.22 102.92 134.33 106.17 147.15 109.84 C 151.24 111.19 155.73 112.06 159.07 114.97 C 161.95 117.47 162.87 121.37 163.27 125.01 C 165.05 141.64 166.93 158.27 168.77 174.90 C 125.92 175.12 83.07 174.96 40.22 174.98 C 41.72 159.42 43.69 143.91 45.28 128.35 C 45.85 124.11 45.87 119.31 48.91 115.95 C 52.21 112.23 57.33 111.28 61.84 109.81 Z" />
        </svg>
```

---

**Дополнительный вопрос 2:**

> Нужно получить такой результат, но только иконку запихнуть в `setStyleSheet` и изменение `clicked` поменять на `hover` (не при нажатии а при наведении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from base64 import b64encode


def iconFromBase64(base_64):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(base_64), "SVG")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    return icon


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self, objectName="pb", clicked=self.onClick)
        self.pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.pb.setCheckable(True)

        self.svgColor("#00f")

        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)          
        self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)
        self.pb.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    def onClick(self, state):
        if state: self.svgColor("#f00")
        else: self.svgColor("#00f")

        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)
        self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)

    def svgColor(self, color):
        self.svg_str = """
        <svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210">
        <path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 98.40 35.63 C 111.65 32.59 126.16 40.12 131.49 52.58 C 136.11 62.55 134.02 74.42 128.61 83.64 C 124.15 91.40 116.88 98.21 107.79 99.72 C 99.82 101.08 91.82 97.30 86.36 91.64 C 78.79 83.85 74.13 72.88 74.99 61.94 C 75.94 49.30 85.95 38.02 98.40 35.63 Z" />
        <path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 61.84 109.81 C 74.62 106.15 87.71 102.93 101.06 102.60 C 99.42 118.09 97.06 133.51 95.27 148.98 C 95.06 150.30 95.92 151.44 96.44 152.58 C 99.06 157.18 101.67 161.78 104.39 166.32 C 107.41 161.59 110.17 156.70 112.88 151.80 C 113.76 150.47 113.66 148.84 113.47 147.33 C 111.62 132.42 109.51 117.54 107.82 102.61 C 121.22 102.92 134.33 106.17 147.15 109.84 C 151.24 111.19 155.73 112.06 159.07 114.97 C 161.95 117.47 162.87 121.37 163.27 125.01 C 165.05 141.64 166.93 158.27 168.77 174.90 C 125.92 175.12 83.07 174.96 40.22 174.98 C 41.72 159.42 43.69 143.91 45.28 128.35 C 45.85 124.11 45.87 119.31 48.91 115.95 C 52.21 112.23 57.33 111.28 61.84 109.81 Z" />
        </svg>
        """ % (color, color)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.resize(300, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.
Приведите пример того, что у вас есть и объясните лучше, что не получается.

Comment: добавил код программы

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы ваш svg в коде можно было использовать внутри стилей QSS?

Comment: в принципе да, но вот теперь думаю надо ли оно...? Может просто сделать контейнер QFrame внутри которого еще один QFrame с svg файлом,а при наведении менять цвет фона первого QFrame, при необходимости в настройках менять свой svg получится та же самая кнопка

Comment: Похоже, qss не поддерживает указание содержимого -- а только ссылками, например на файлы в ресурсах. Сделал конвертирование в base64: `svg_base64_str = b64encode(svg_str.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')` и в css `"background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64," + svg_base64_str + "');\n"` (как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866111/5909792) и нифига

Comment: а есть ли возможность вставить ссылку на ресурс в QSS через файл res.py (link(res.icon)) по типу Windows (\sell32.dll, 12) ?

Comment: Кстати, а можете попробовать что-то подобное?: self.pb.setStyleSheet("#pb {\n"
        "background-image: url(%s);\n"
        "}" % svg_str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвет изменить можно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from base64 import b64encode


def iconFromBase64(base_64):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(base_64), "SVG")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    return icon


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self, objectName="pb", clicked=self.onClick)
        self.pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.pb.setCheckable(True)

        self.svgWidget = QSvgWidget(self)
        self.svgWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 100, 100))

        self.svgColor("#00f")

        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)          
        self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)
        self.pb.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.setWindowIcon(self.icon)

    def onClick(self, state):
        if state: self.svgColor("#f00")
        else: self.svgColor("#00f")

        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)
        self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)

    def svgColor(self, color):
        self.svg_str = """
        <svg viewBox="0 0 160 160" width="160" height="160">
          <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" />
          <g transform=" matrix(0.866, -0.5, 0.25, 0.433, 80, 80)">
            <path d="M 0,70 A 65,70 0 0,0 65,0 5,5 0 0,1 75,0 75,70 0 0,1 0,70Z" fill="%s">
              <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 0 0" to="0 0 0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </path>
          </g>
          <path d="M 50,0 A 50,50 0 0,0 -50,0Z" transform="matrix(0.866, -0.5, 0.5, 0.866, 80, 80)" />
        </svg>
        """ % color   
        self.svgWidget.load(self.svg_str.encode() )     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.resize(300, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но на Иконке оно не жужжит :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Комментарий к дополнительному вопросу:**

Если вы вставляете несколько значений, то вам надо передать список:

```
print("""
1 = %s
2 = %s
3 = %s""" % ("один", "два", "три"))
```

Вывод:

```
1 = один
2 = два
3 = три
```

---

> Нужно получить такой результат, но только иконку запихнуть в setStyleSheet и изменение clicked поменять на hover (не при нажатии а при наведении)

Я добавил кнопку с реализацией `hover`.

Если вы хотите чтобы иконки находились в модуле и применять `StyleSheet`,
надо сформировать файл ресурсов.
Как создает файл ресурсов и загрузить изображение из файла ресурсов
смотрите здесь : [Как скомпилировать .py в .exe с картинкой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from base64 import b64encode


def iconFromBase64(base_64):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(base_64), "SVG")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    return icon


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):                          # <---
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        pass

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("#f00")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("#00f")     


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self, objectName="pb", clicked=self.onClick)
        self.pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.pb.setCheckable(True)

        self.pb_2 = PushButton(self)                               # <-----
        self.pb_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 100, 100))
        self.pb_2.hover.connect(self.onHover) #svgColor)

        self.svgColor("#00f")
        self.set_icon()
        self.onHover("#00f")

    def onClick(self, state):
        if state: self.svgColor("#f00")
        else: self.svgColor("#00f")
        self.set_icon()

    def svgColor(self, color):
        self.svg_str = """
        <svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210">
        <path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 98.40 35.63 C 111.65 32.59 126.16 40.12 131.49 52.58 C 136.11 62.55 134.02 74.42 128.61 83.64 C 124.15 91.40 116.88 98.21 107.79 99.72 C 99.82 101.08 91.82 97.30 86.36 91.64 C 78.79 83.85 74.13 72.88 74.99 61.94 C 75.94 49.30 85.95 38.02 98.40 35.63 Z" />
        <path fill="%s" opacity="1.00" d=" M 61.84 109.81 C 74.62 106.15 87.71 102.93 101.06 102.60 C 99.42 118.09 97.06 133.51 95.27 148.98 C 95.06 150.30 95.92 151.44 96.44 152.58 C 99.06 157.18 101.67 161.78 104.39 166.32 C 107.41 161.59 110.17 156.70 112.88 151.80 C 113.76 150.47 113.66 148.84 113.47 147.33 C 111.62 132.42 109.51 117.54 107.82 102.61 C 121.22 102.92 134.33 106.17 147.15 109.84 C 151.24 111.19 155.73 112.06 159.07 114.97 C 161.95 117.47 162.87 121.37 163.27 125.01 C 165.05 141.64 166.93 158.27 168.77 174.90 C 125.92 175.12 83.07 174.96 40.22 174.98 C 41.72 159.42 43.69 143.91 45.28 128.35 C 45.85 124.11 45.87 119.31 48.91 115.95 C 52.21 112.23 57.33 111.28 61.84 109.81 Z" />
        </svg>
        """ % (color, color)    

    def set_icon(self):
        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)          
        self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)
        self.pb.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))    

    def onHover(self, color):
        self.svgColor(color)
        svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
        self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)   
        self.pb_2.setIcon(self.icon)
        self.pb_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.resize(300, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @biomotor см. обновление

Comment: Большое спасибо, я в принципе уже думал о чем-то подобном но не знал как реализовать.

Comment: @biomotor если мои ответы помогли вам, не забывайте отметить их как правильные и  полезные .

Comment: а почему не получается добавить стиль к этой кнопке?         self.pb_2.setStyleSheet("#pb_2 {\n"
        "border: 1px solid #666666;\n"
        "background-color: #E5E5E5;\n"
        "}")

Comment: @biomotor  добавьте `self.pb_2.setObjectName("pb_2")`