# Как закрепить изображение для Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qrc

Есть такой код из *Qt Designer*:

```py
self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
self.label.setEnabled(True)
self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 441, 481))
self.label.setText("")
self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../image.png"))
self.label.setScaledContents(True)
self.label.setObjectName("label")
```

То есть просто вывод изображения в `label` через `QPixmap`, но проблема в том, что используя относительный путь к изображению, при перемещении скомпилированной программы картинка теряется, что логично, но она бы потерялась и залив я куда нибудь эту программу.

**Вопрос** - возможно ли закрепить за программой изображение, чтобы, например, в скомпилированном виде (`pyinstaller`) она сохранялась?

---

**main.py**

```py
from trackshakeFront import *
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QLabel


import sys


class trackWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(trackWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('TRACKTRACKER')

        self.buttonCool.clicked.connect(self.addCool)
        self.buttonMaggot.clicked.connect(self.addMaggot)
        self.buttonMoney.clicked.connect(self.showMoney)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel(self, pixmap=QPixmap(":/trackshake/trackshake.png")))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = trackWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**trackshakeFront.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(456, 660)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(456, 660))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(456, 800))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 96, 98))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(244, 48, 50))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(156, 0, 2))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(244, 127, 129))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 96, 98))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(244, 48, 50))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(156, 0, 2))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(244, 127, 129))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 96, 98))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(244, 48, 50))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(156, 0, 2))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 0, 1))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(234, 0, 3))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../trackshake/trackshake.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.buttonMoney = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonMoney.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 500, 141, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ink Free")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.buttonMoney.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMoney.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color: #ffa4ea;\n"
"    border: #ffbefa\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #ffbefa, stop: 1 #ffbefa);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonMoney.setObjectName("buttonMoney")
        self.buttonMaggot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonMaggot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 500, 141, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ink Free")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.buttonMaggot.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMaggot.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color: #ffa4ea;\n"
"    border: #ffbefa\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #ffbefa, stop: 1 #ffbefa);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonMaggot.setObjectName("buttonMaggot")
        self.lineMoney = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineMoney.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 570, 141, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.lineMoney.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lineMoney.setFont(font)
        self.lineMoney.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"    border: black;\n"
"    background-color: #ff6769;\n"
"}")
        self.lineMoney.setMaxLength(6)
        self.lineMoney.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineMoney.setObjectName("lineMoney")
        self.lineMaggot = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineMaggot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 570, 141, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.lineMaggot.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lineMaggot.setFont(font)
        self.lineMaggot.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"    border: black;\n"
"    background-color: #ff6769;\n"
"}")
        self.lineMaggot.setMaxLength(3)
        self.lineMaggot.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineMaggot.setObjectName("lineMaggot")
        self.buttonCool = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonCool.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 141, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 151, 222))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(247, 134, 247))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 151, 222))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(247, 134, 247))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 164, 234))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 151, 222))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(247, 134, 247))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        self.buttonCool.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ink Free")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.buttonCool.setFont(font)
        self.buttonCool.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color: #ffa4ea;\n"
"    border: #ffbefa\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #ffbefa, stop: 1 #ffbefa);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonCool.setObjectName("buttonCool")
        self.lineCool = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineCool.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 141, 61))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 149, 151))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 142, 144))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 149, 151))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 149, 151))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 103, 105))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        self.lineCool.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lineCool.setFont(font)
        self.lineCool.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"    border: black;\n"
"    background-color: #ff6769;\n"
"}")
        self.lineCool.setMaxLength(3)
        self.lineCool.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineCool.setObjectName("lineCool")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 441, 481))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../trackshake/trackshake.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.buttonMoney.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "$$MONEY$$", None, -1))
        self.buttonMaggot.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MAGGOTS", None, -1))
        self.lineMoney.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "0", None, -1))
        self.lineMaggot.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "0", None, -1))
        self.buttonCool.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "COOLERS", None, -1))
        self.lineCool.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "0", None, -1))
```

**qrc file**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>trachshake/trachshake.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

И еще у меня остался единственный после конвертации файл **`.py`**, ибо потом вдруг команда `pyrcc5 res_1.qrc -o res_1_rc.py` стала возвращать ошибку о не нахождении файла..

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то возможно вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699

Comment: опубликуйте вашу модули (включая .qrc), для воспроизведения ошибки о которой вы пишите.

Comment: @S.Nick изменил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Несовпадение имени папки в файле ресурсов и `QPixmap(":/trackshake/trackshake.png")`

   `<RCC>
     <qresource prefix="/">
       <file>trachshake/trachshake.png</file>
     </qresource>
   </RCC>`
2. Добавил импорт `import res_Ok_rc`
3. Исправил имя родителя `layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)`

Все остальные действия, как указано в ссылке [Как скомпилировать .py в .exe с картинкой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699)

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets
#from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QLabel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from trackshakeFront import Ui_MainWindow

import res_Ok_rc                                        # +++ Здесь мы импортируем наше изображение

class trackWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(trackWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('TRACKTRACKER')

        self.buttonCool.clicked.connect(self.addCool)
        self.buttonMaggot.clicked.connect(self.addMaggot)
        self.buttonMoney.clicked.connect(self.showMoney)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                    # - (self)

#        layout.addWidget(QLabel(self, pixmap=QPixmap(":/trackshake/trackshake.png")))
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(self, pixmap=QPixmap(":/trackshake/Ok.png")))

    def addCool(self):
        pass

    def addMaggot(self):
        pass

    def showMoney(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = trackWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**qrc file**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>trackshake/Ok.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все сработало, но не подскажите, как отрегулировать размер, а то
https://ibb.co/T269Wyr

Comment: @finally это уже другой вопрос. Задайте новый вопрос, приложите минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @finally при том что это новый вопрос. 
Если на скорую руку, то попробуйте 
`layout.addWidget(QLabel(self, pixmap=QPixmap(":/trackshake/trackshake.png").scaled(441, 481)))`