# Как добавить фотографию в pyqt5 для конвертации в exe формат

Tags: python, pyqt5, picturebox

Я пользуюсь qt5 графическим редактором для python. Мне нужно добавить фотографию, как `background`. Но я столкнулся с проблемой при использование обычного `label` с путём файла, при конвертации файла в exe формат с помощью `pyinstalle`r фото просто нет.

Я помню, что можно это было как-то сделать через `qrc`, но я пишу код вручную и не знаю, как это правильно можно реализовать. Вот как выглядит строчки на `label`. +++ это в класс виджета. Ресурс файл есть. Всё в корне.

```
import resources

pixmap = QPixmap("ZeXsPua_AKU.png")
```

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо добавить к проекту файл ресурсов.
например
resources.qrc

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>picture.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

который потом надо конвертнуть `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`
и использовать в таком виде

```
import resources
...
pixmap = QPixmap(":/newPrefix/picture.png")
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что надо делать с первым кодом? И почему мы конвертируем из py в qrc? + будет ли это работать, если у человека нет на пк этой фотографии, только exe.

Comment: первый кусок это содержимое файла ресурсов resources.qrc из которого потом с использованием pyrcc5 необходимо сгенерировать модуль resources.py для импорта

Comment: теперь понял. Тогда следующий вопрос во втором коде  при запуске фото не высвечивается, а если оставить старый код, то в exe фото не вшыта и пк её не находит.

Comment: проверьте что у вас получилось в resources.py. какого он размера?

Comment: resources весит 2739кб.

Comment: добавьте тогда в вопрос что у вас получилось и в программе и в .qrc возможно вы неверно указываете ресурс

Comment: Добавил всё, можете проверить.

Answer (score 3):

В комментах можно долго писать. Для простоты давайте так. простейший пример.

у меня в одном каталоге лежат:
test.py, image.png, resources.qrc
сама программа test.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import resources

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap(":/newPrefix/image.png")
        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)      
        self.show()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

файл ресурсов resources.qrc такого вида:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>image.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

для начала запускаем `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc` и получаем в этом же каталоге модуль resources.py

теперь я могу сделать exe и передать на другой комп: `pyinstaller --onefile test.py`

Comment: сейчас проверю. спасибо за помощь в любом случае.