# Фоновая картинка PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Как можно вставить картинку фоном. Нижеприведенный вариант кода не срабатывает

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTitle("...")
        self.setSubTitle("...")

        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_3.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_4.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        
        self.listCheckBox = [self.checkBox_1, self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox_4] 
        self.a = 0                                                                                    

    def check(self, state):
        self.a = 0                                               
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            a = a + 1
        for checkBox in self.listCheckBox:                       
            if checkBox.isChecked():                              
                self.a += 1                                      
        print(self.a)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class4

stylesheet = '''
    QWidget {
        background-image: url("C:\111.jpg");
    }
'''
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

    w = ClassesPage1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась как

```
stylesheet = '''
    QWidget {
        background-image: url("C:/111.png"); #С jpg не хочет работать, тем не менее
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt штатно с jpg не работает. "Из коробки" есть поддержки png (про остальные врать не буду). Для того чтобы корректно работало с jpg необходимо с приложением таскать imageformats\qjpeg.dll

Далее. Если есть желание интегрировать картинку в приложение и не таскать ее отдельно, см. ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1125878/365297

Answer (score 0):

Вы адрес картинки с диска указали, насколько я знаю нужно создать свой "архив" в qt designer.
Открываете стили элемента, >добавить ресурс>нажмите на карандаш>кнопка слева внизу создать этот архив>первая кнопка второй строчки "добавить приставку".