# Не читается видео в ресурсах при создании exe файла python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно запустить видео в программе. При отладке в VSCode все работает, вот тому пример:
[image: Работа видео при отладке в VSCode]

Но при создании exe файла видео не запускается(просто черный экран), вот результат:
[image: Запуск exe файла, видео не работает]

Файл ресурсов существует, вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить фотографию в pyqt5 для конвертации в exe формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125876/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-pyqt5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: не считаю дубликатом, т.к. там пример с картинкой, которые есть в моем коде и они работают. Я спрашиваю именно про видео, потому что при прописывании пути к файлу ресурсов они не работают. У меня имеются эти файлы ресурсов

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Покажите ваши файлы ресурсов. Покажите как вы создаете exe-файл

Comment: @S.Nick, пожалуйста посмотрите, я добавил примеры как Вы просили

Comment: Sorry, но я особо ничего не прочил. Я вас предоставил ссылку. в которой написано, что вам  надо сделать чтобы желающие  вам помочь, попробовали для вас что-то сделать. А вы предоставили какие-то не очень понятные картинки и что ...

Comment: Попробуйте задать путь без qrc - `":/content..."`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, не работает по прежнему

Answer (score 1):

Ребзя, проблема решена! Поменял расширение файла и все заработало, не знаю почему он не хочет читать с ресурсов файлы .mp4. Конвертировал в .mpg и загнал обратно в ресурсы и всё заработало. Теперь без посторонних файлов запускается в едином .exe-шнике. А так путь такой же

```py
self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(f"qrc:resources/{name_vid}")))
```