# Как расположить фото в виджете PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qrc

Подскажите с проблемой:
Работаю с *PyQt5* (`QPixmap`), вставляю фотографию в виджет `QLabel`.
Указываю путь к расположению фотографии и она располагается на виджете,
но если удаляю фотографию из папки, где находится проект, то соответственно и открывать то нечего.

Как можно установить фото так, чтобы оно уже всегда загружалось, не зависимо от того, есть это фото в папке с проектом или нет?

Для начала захожу в папку с проектом.py.
Создаю текстовый док., прописываю туда эти строки:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="main">
    <file>photo.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

сохраняю как `resources.qrc`

Далее прописываю в ком. строке:

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

В основном коде прописываю `import resources`, но фото также не появилось.

Рабочий код, когда фото расположено в папке с проектом:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class ImageViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('photo.jpg')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Image Viewer')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    image_viewer = ImageViewer()
    image_viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Об этом уже много раз писалось, вам надо создать файл ресурсов. Полистайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: нашли и разобрались?

Comment: @S. Nick нет. Подправил основной текст, посмотрите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Создаем файл ресурсов например `kik.qrc`

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>images/head.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Предполагаем, что картинка `head.jpg` находится в каталоге `images` (images/head.jpg)

2. Загрузить изображение из файла ресурсов:

Команда преобразования `pyrcc5 kik.qrc -o  kik_rc.py`

Этот способ заключается в том, чтобы преобразовать файл `kik.qrc` в файл `kik_rc.py`
Все картинка в `kik_rc.py`

3. Обратите внимание как прописать путь к изображению !

---

```
#       ----->>>> v   видите двоеточие !  
pixmap = QPixmap(':/images/head.jpg')
```

**q1201338.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import kik_rc                                     # Здесь мы импортируем наше изображение

class ImageViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QLabel(self)                      #  v
        pixmap = QPixmap(':/images/head.jpg')     # ':/images/head.jpg'
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Image Viewer')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    image_viewer = ImageViewer()
    image_viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как выглядит каталог? Просто название папки, где хранится qrc файл? Или путь от диска С до qrc файла? У меня в папке main лежит и код и qrc файл. Какой каталог прописывать для qrc файла?

Comment: @Евгений  если как по моему примеру, то в папке `main` создайте папку `images` и положите туда изображение.

Comment: но если передать файл.py другу, сохранится ли фото? Или нужно передать не только py, но и еще преобразованный kik_rc.py?

Comment: @Евгений да, надо передать и `kik_rc.py`

Comment: а есть способ сохранить фото так, чтобы передавать только один py файл?

Comment: @Евгений нет, или два или один exe-шник - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699

Comment: а если я весь код из kik_rc.py вставлю в начало кода? Основного кода.py. Понимаю, код огромный, но так будет работать?

Comment: Получается один файл, и если передать другу, то заработает?

Comment: @Евгений вы заглядывали в `kik_rc.py` ? Я не пробовал, хотите проверить - попробуйте.  The END.