# Как правильно хранить картинки, используя Qt Designer и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть файл интерфейса `.ui`, созданный в `Qt Designer` и код к этому файлу на Python, IDE - PyCharm.

Так вот, я добавляла картинки через `QLabel`, указывая путь к файлу на локальном компьютере. И при запуске на другом ПК или даже при изменении расположения файла интерфейса, картинки не отображаются. Ну это понятно, потому что я указывала полные пути.

Сейчас попробовала создать файл ресурсов, добавить туда картинку и с него загрузить картинку в `QLabel`, в самом `Qt Designer` это сработало, но при перемещении файла интерфейса, картинка не отображается.

Как правильно добавлять картинки в `Qt Designer`, чтобы они подгружались? Я ещё пробовала хранить картинки в корневой папке `img`, с расчётом на то, что будет использоваться *относительный путь*, но это также не сработало.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: отвечает ли это на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699

Comment: @S.Nick да, спасибо