# Секундомер и звуковой сигнал

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtimer, qsound

У меня есть секундомер. Когда наступает определенное время, например,
5 секунд :- (`if i == 5`)

должен прозвучать сигнал :

`winsound.PlaySound("gong1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)`

И вроде всё работает, но секундомер останавливается, пока звук не закончится.

Я нагуглил про `Thread`, но не смог разобраться, как его применять.

Как сделать так, чтобы секундомер продолжал работать и проигрывался звук?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import winsound
from threading import Thread


class mainClass():
    def update_time(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):

            if i == 5:
                self.sound_gong()
            print(i)


    def sound_gong(self):
        winsound.PlaySound("gong1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    th = Thread(target=update_time)
    th.start()

k = mainClass()
k.update_time()
```

Comment: Пару вопросов можно? Вы будете использовать библиотеку PyQt5?

Comment: Звук должен каждую секунду звучать?

Comment: Звук не каждую секунду,  а за 15 секунд до конца раунда( в примере кода я указал, что звук включается,  когда i становится больше 5). И да,  я буду использовать библиотеку pyqt

Comment: Примите ответ, который вам лучше всего помог — галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: Сорри, забыл про галку

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы заговорили о `PyQt5`, то дополнительный поток вам не нужен.

> Класс `QSound` предоставляет метод для воспроизведения звуковых файлов `.wav`.
>
> `Qt` обеспечивает наиболее часто используемую операцию со звуком в приложениях с
> графическим интерфейсом пользователя: асинхронное воспроизведение звукового файла.
> Проще всего это сделать с помощью статической функции `play()`:

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html#details

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, \
    QLCDNumber, QGridLayout, QSpinBox, QAbstractSpinBox 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lcd = QLCDNumber()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start", clicked=self.timerStart)
        self.buttonReset = QPushButton("Reset", clicked=self.timerReset)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox.PlusMinus)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(222)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 7)
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(True)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)       
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lcd, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonReset, 2, 1)
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)                            
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                   
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)                              # 1 sec
        
        self.time = 0
        self.sound = QSound('D:/_Qt/Mp3/zvuki_prirody-td.wav')    # QSound

    def showTime(self):  
        self.lcd.display(self.time)
        self.time += 1                               
        if self.time > self.spinBox.value(): 
            self.timer.stop()
            self.button.setText("Start")
            self.time = 0
            self.sound.stop()
        elif self.time == 5:           # когда наступает определенное время, например 5 секунд
            self.sound.play()

    def timerStart(self):
        if self.button.text() == "Start":
            self.timer.start()
            self.button.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.timer.stop()       
            self.button.setText("Start")

    def timerReset(self):
        self.timer.stop()       
        self.button.setText("Start")
        self.time = 0
        self.lcd.display(self.time)
        self.sound.stop()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")                    
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 150)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ник, привет! Большое вам спасибо! Писал комментарий утром, но что-то он не появился! Большое вам спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, а относительный пусть я могу указать для файла? почему-то у меня не получается. К примеру, я закинул файл в папку и пишу вот так, ```self.sound = QSound(":/Audio/gong1.wav")``` не выходит, а полный путь выходит. и второе, как правильно добавить этот звук в файл ресурсов?

Comment: @dutik попробуйте так "/Audio/gong1.wav"  или так "Audio/gong1.wav".

Comment: да,я пробовал все варианты, не понимаю пока, почему относительный путь указывается по разному для разных методов. Ник, а как мне добавить этот звук в фал ресурсов. для шрифта я указывал ```if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/Fonts/DS-Digital.ttf")```

Comment: также как и картинки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-py-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/998699#998699

Comment: + https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Спасибо! Буду изучать!

Comment: @dutik пожалуйста, если что-то найдете нужное для себя, не забудьте отметить ответ как полезный.

Comment: Ник, извините, пожалуйста, а можете объяснить, почему, когда я делаю относительный путь ```self.sound_gong1 = QSound("audio/gong1.wav")```, то при компиляции звук не воспроизводится, а когда я указываю абсолютный ```self.sound_gong1 = QSound(":/audio/gong1.wav")```, то звук в скомпилированном файле появляется?

Comment: @dutik если вы используете файл ресурсов, то писать надо так - `":/audio/gong1.wav"`. Если НЕ используете файл ресурсов, то писать надо так `"./audio/gong1.wav"` или так `"audio/gong1.wav"`.

Comment: Получается,  что при использовании файла-ресурса  ВСЕГДА нужно использовать абсолютный путь,  верно?

Comment: @dutik  нет, `":/audio/gong1.wav"` - это не абсолютный путь, а такая форма записи.

Answer (score 3):

Ну по-хорошему структура должна быть какая-то такая. Тред вам нужен, чтобы вызвать проигрывание звука в отдельном параллельном потоке. У меня винды под рукой нет, поэтому я имитирую звук просто печатью текста. Но как видим, счёт времени во время "проигрывания звука" не прерывается:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class mainClass():
    def update_time(self):
        th_gong = Thread(target=self.sound_gong)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if i == 5:
                th_gong.start()
            print(i)
            sleep(1)
        th_gong.join()

    def sound_gong(self):
        print('Bim!')
        sleep(3)
        print('Bom!')
        #winsound.PlaySound("gong1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)

k = mainClass()
k.update_time()
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
Bim!
5
6
7
Bom!
8
9
```

Comment: большое спасибо! Сейчас,  когда увидел ответ,  кажется,  что это так просто!